# Why is SVM Classifier model predicting the same label for every image?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision, svm

I am developing a project ASL gesture recognition. I have used the following dataset
https://www.kaggle.com/ayuraj/american-sign-language-dataset.

It is a multiclass problem. 
I have extracted the features from these images and I have developed a csv file which consists of 18 columns and 18150 rows. Also, I have normalized the features using MinMaxScaler(). The first 17 columns represent the features and the last column represents the class. I have trained a SVM classifier model by using the following code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\newDataset\Features\combined.csv', usecols = ['0', '1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', 'Class'])

array=dataset.values

X=array[:,0:17]

Y=array[:,17]

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

model=OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='poly', C=8,degree=3)).fit(X_train,Y_train)

filename = 'SVM.pkl'

joblib.dump(model, filename)

loaded_model = joblib.load(filename)

predictions=loaded_model.predict(X_test)

print(accuracy_score(Y_test, predictions))

print(confusion_matrix(Y_test, predictions))

print(classification_report(Y_test, predictions))
```

The output is attached below:
[https://imgur.com/a/w9qv1Qk][1]

This classifier model is predicting the same label, even if I pass the image from the training dataset.Also, can the precision and recall value be same in the classficiation report?

Comment: Welcome to SO; for the next time, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you this time).

Comment: can you put some rows of your dataset? also try to predict directly from the model not the pickle and let me know..

Comment: @Ehsan [https://imgur.com/a/NivRNX8] Image of dataset ..... Here 1 corresponds to A

Comment: I cant open the link. neither the top one. IDK!!

Comment: @Ehsan Sorry here is the ouptut [https://i.imgur.com/jgQsEqk.png]

Comment: Here is the dataset [https://i.imgur.com/wcO7Ol0.png]. Is it visible now?